# How force Application.Volatile to end or to specific work -book/-sheet

Tags: vba

Is there any way to switch off Application.Volatile or run in specific range/workbook? I use in my code function as below:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)

    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)

End Function
```

I tried  Application.Volatile (False) but didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)

    Application.Volatile False
    Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)

End Function
```

MS REFERENCE DOC:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile

Comment: Yeah, it stopped evaluating, but seems like is still doing something in background because Excel still is working very slowly...

Comment: There are millions of reasons that could be. If this answers your question please mark it with the green check mark to close this question. You can open a new one for any additional help you need.